# How to show 2 populations types in one bar using chartjs?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, chart.js

I am developing a Ruby on Rails application, and I would like to visualize my results in a chart bar. I want to visualize in one bar 2 population kinds, for example male and female with 2 different colours.

For designing my chart I use the chartjs, the following has its documentation.

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Stacked Bar Chart - the one linked to from the Community Extensions section of the ChartJS site - http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-community-extensions

https://github.com/Regaddi/Chart.StackedBar.js

With the library and the extension included, you call it just as you would a normal ChartJS chart.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var myBar = new Chart(ctx).StackedBar(barChartData);
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/42s1naq9/

---

[image]